# How can i use EventArgsConverter in prism InvokeCommandAction?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to use EventArgsConverter on my project, based on this post:

(https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/pull/14)

My problem is that I am not sure where b is referring to? Or where can I download a full sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The b: is the xmlns reference to xaml behaviors which is now a nuget package

See

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/

As in

```
 xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

Working markup and code:

```
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Button>
            <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCommand}" />
                </b:EventTrigger>
            </b:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Viewmodel:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private ICommand _testCommand;
        public ICommand TestCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_testCommand == null)
                {
                    _testCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        p => true,
                        p => this.TestMethod());
                }
                return _testCommand;
            }
        }
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("It worked !!!");
        }
    }
```

When I click the button, the messagebox appears.

Comment: Thank you for your response
but this reference has no InvokeCommandAction

Comment: I've added working markup and code which illustrate this working. Don't forget to add the xaml behaviors nuget package if you are replicating this.